# A collection of pairwise disjoint events with nonzero probability must be countable

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I'm trying to figure this problem out, and I keep getting stuck. I was hoping someone could help me get started:

Let $(A)_{\beta \in B}$ be a collection of pairwise disjoint events. Show that if $P(A_{\beta}) > 0$ for each $\beta$, then $B$ is either finite or countable.

I started by assuming that $B$ was uncountable by way of contradiction. Then I took a countable subset $B_0\subseteq B$ and observed that $P(\bigcup_{\beta \in B} A_\beta) = \sum_{\beta \in B} P(A_\beta) > 0$, but I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: No uncountable sum of positive terms can converge.  Indeed, at least one of the intervals $(\frac 1{n+1}, \frac 1n]$ must contain infinitely many terms in the sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $n \in \mathbb N$ let $B_n = \{\beta \in B \mid P(A_\beta) \gt 1/n\}$. As $(A_\beta)_{\beta \in B}$ is a collection of pairwise disjoint events, we have $\vert B_n \vert \le n$. Then

$$B = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb N} B_n$$ which is a countable union of finite sets, is therefore countable.